# I can't wrap my head around $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ in Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right. He defines $F^S$ to be the set of functions from $S$ to $F$.

So for example, $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ is the set of all functions from $0$ to $1$ that map $\mathbb R$. So does this mean for all elements in $[0,1]$, these elements can have functions assigned to them, (infinitely many functions I assume), and by doing so, this will map out all of $\mathbb R$?

For example if you fix the function $f(x)= x + 1$ and make the domain $[0,1]$ you would get the image $[1,2]$, which would be some values of $\mathbb R$, but not all. Then you would find infinitely many other functions that map out the rest of it? And all of these would go into the set? Let me know what you guys think.

Comment: It just means the functions from $[0,1] $ to $\mathbb{R}$. so $f(x) = x^2$ in the set, $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is in the set, and many, many more.

Comment: $f \in R^[{^0}{^,}{^1}{^]}$ iff $f$ is a function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. The definition you quoted does not impose any other requirements on $f$, in particular it does not need to be surjective, so it needs not "*map out all of* $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In addition, you can consider the collection of constant functions $f\in R^{[0,1]}$ indexed by $x$ in R,  defined by $f(t)=x$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. This collection shows that the union of the images of all the functions is indeed $R$

Comment: Thanks so much guys answers my question!

Comment: @ElchananSolomon : If your comment answers the question, it should be posted as an answer, especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.  In general, questions should not be answered in comments.

Comment: See my edits to the question for proper MathJax usage. In particular, $A^{[0,1]}$ is coded as `A^{[0,1]}`. $\qquad$

Comment: The notation $f: S \to F$ just means that the output of $f$ is always an element of $F$. It doesn't mean that *every* element of $F$ is a possible output of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example:
\begin{align}
& \{0,1\}^{\{a,b,c\}} \\[10pt] = {} & \left\{ \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto0 \\ b\mapsto0 \\
c\mapsto0 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto0 \\ b\mapsto0 \\
c\mapsto1 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto0 \\ b\mapsto1 \\
c\mapsto0 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto1 \\ b\mapsto0 \\
c\mapsto0 \end{array} \right], \right. \\[10pt]
& \qquad \left. \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto0 \\ b\mapsto1 \\
c\mapsto1 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto1 \\ b\mapsto0 \\
c\mapsto1 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto1 \\ b\mapsto1 \\
c\mapsto0 \end{array} \right], \left[ \begin{array}{l} a\mapsto1 \\ b\mapsto1 \\
c\mapsto1 \end{array} \right] \right\}.
\end{align}

It's the set of all functions whose domain is $\{a,b,c\}$ and whose codomain is $\{0,1\}.$